# NAS Compression/Decompression

Tags: network-shares, nas, samba, compression, storage

I'm interested in building a NAS to act as a file server for a small number of people (myself being the sole user the majority of the time).  I'm thinking the server would run on linux and serve files with Samba to my computer, which dual boots linux Mint and Windows 10, and my phone, which runs on Android.  The NAS would utilize only SATA-HDD drives, and would be made from an embedded, low-powered device like this one:

[Asrock J4105](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079GHRQD9)

The NAS also would be performing frequent writes to the drives in the background, accessing and appending data to a few thousand small .csv files a day.

I've been reading online that NAS drives can compress data during transfer to increase transfer speeds, and that compression also can significantly reduce on-drive storage space.  However, I had some questions:

1. If these .csv files are compressed on the device to save space, is there a significant time or CPU usage penalty when they need to be re-accessed again?  Would a faster compression method like gunzip be viable for compressing them?
2. If the files are compressed on the NAS, would they be received decompressed by the devices running Windows, linux Mint, and Android as part of the network compression/decompression, or would they be received as compressed files that would then need to be processed?
3. The J4105 CPU has Hardware Accelerated Encode. Could this possibly be used to increase compression/decompression speeds of files that are being accessed?

Comment: How do you plan on compressing them on disk?

Comment: I was planning on using gunzip or bzip2 to compress each .csv file individually

Comment: As you said "small files" I expect that will not save much space, as each file has a minimum size on disk (ie block size of filesystem). On small files there is a significant saving to be had by putting multiple files in an archive. Gunzip is going to give slightly less compression but will be significantly faster - although this  will only be noticeable on large files. I would not do this as it will be painful to use client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot to unpack here - First to answer the questioned as asked -

1. This depends on compression type and level. It won't be noticeable on small files either way. It would likely have an all-round negative effect on typical large files.
2. It is unclear how you intend to implement compression. If you naively use bzip/bzip, then it will be quite impractical and present compressed files to the clients. More on this below.
3. Unlikely. You would need to find/create a compression programming that can take advantage of these functions - but the functions are not designed for this purpose (they are for handling video, which is entirely different, and, for a start, usually lossy.

**Comments/Thoughts/Suggestions**

I would be wary of compression - it adds complexity (especially if you are in a potential data loss situation). Most files are either to small to be of concern or already compressed. HDD is cheap.

If using compression, look at a mechanism which acts at the filesystem level or  presents as a virtual filesystem - in this way it can be seemless. Apparently btrfs can do this.

You might want to look at encryption at rest. LUKS can make use of AES-NI instructions (ie CPU hardware on most CPUs including the J4105) so its got low impact on performance. If your hard disk fails, it can be useful knowing your data is unreadable if you want to RMA or throw away the drive. You will need a mechanism to provide a key on startup. I've taken to using a USB key left in the machine (making sure its backed up).

You have not mentioned RAID. If you want reliability, you want RAID1 or 10. Don't mess around with RAID0,5 or 6. Also, RAID is not backup. Also, ensure you monitor your RAID array status.

You have not mentioned disk management. As you have not got a system with ecc memory, avoid ZFS, and be sure to use LVM.

Have a look at Owncloud/Next cloud - it provides cross-platform Dropbox like functionality and can likely be hosted on your NAS.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent analysis!  BTRFS seems like what I was looking for.   I hadn't decided on any of the disk management/backup/encryption but the suggestions are very helpful!  I think compression would definitely help in my particular use case.  When I tested compressing the files, they shrink to 7-25% of their original size.  This translates to massive storage savings compared to the multiple terabytes of data I calculate the .csv files will take up after years of operation.